# How do I start the google drive editors

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, ckeditor, google-drive-api

Google provides several editors for the Google drive documents, and also an [viewer for external document types](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=nl&answer=2423485). I'm already working with the metadata from the drive files, but how do I open these editors from my GWT/GAE code?

Summarized; How do I start the Google editors in a frame from my own GWT website? Is there an API for this?

I already saw the [GDBE project](http://code.google.com/p/gdbe/) but I like to use the standard drive editors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking in **cloudie Web based desktop**;

http://code.google.com/p/cloudie/

The editor is opened in a new window with just an URL parameter ...

```
private void execute(final FileDialogOpenDocumentCommand cmd) 
{
  Window.open("http://docs.google.com/Doc?docid=" + cmd.getDocumentId() +
  "&hl=en",cmd.getDocumentId(), "");
}
```